# Query in a procedure returns different results with hard-coded values and variables

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have this procedure in the pl/sql developer:

```
  procedure CURRICULUM_TRANSLATE2 (DEGRCODE IN OUT VARCHAR2,
                                 COLLCODE IN OUT VARCHAR2,
                                 MAJRCODE IN OUT VARCHAR2,
                                 RESDCODE IN OUT VARCHAR2,
                                 LEVLCODE IN OUT VARCHAR2,
                                 STYPCODE IN OUT VARCHAR2,
                                 TERMCODE IN OUT VARCHAR2,
                                 ATTSCODE IN OUT VARCHAR2,
                                 DEBUGGER IN     VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL)
IS
VARPROG       VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
  SELECT
    T.DEGRCODE,
    T.PROGCODE,
    T.MAJRCODE,
    T.COLLCODE,                             
    T.LEVLCODE,
    T.STYPCODE,
    T.ATTSCODE
  INTO
   DEGRCODE,
   VARPROG ,
   MAJRCODE,
   COLLCODE,                             
   LEVLCODE,
   STYPCODE,
   ATTSCODE
  FROM 
    MAJORLOOKUP T
  JOIN (SELECT SRM_COLLEGE, SRM_DEGREE, SRM_MAJOR, MAX(SRM_TERM_EFFECTIVE) AS MAXTERM
        FROM   MAJORLOOKUP
        WHERE  SRM_TERM_EFFECTIVE <= TERMCODE
        GROUP BY SRM_COLLEGE, SRM_DEGREE, SRM_MAJOR) M  
    ON  M.SRM_COLLEGE = T.SRM_COLLEGE 
    AND M.SRM_DEGREE = T.SRM_DEGREE 
    AND ((T.SRM_MAJOR IS NULL AND M.SRM_MAJOR IS NULL)           OR 
         (T.SRM_MAJOR IS NULL AND M.SRM_MAJOR ='Not Applicable') OR 
         (T.SRM_MAJOR IS NULL AND UPPER(M.SRM_MAJOR) ='NONE')    OR 
         (T.SRM_MAJOR = M.SRM_MAJOR)) 
  WHERE T.SRM_TERM_EFFECTIVE = M.MAXTERM
  AND TRIM(M.SRM_COLLEGE) = TRIM(COLLCODE)
  AND TRIM(M.SRM_DEGREE) = TRIM(DEGRCODE)
  AND ((TRIM(M.SRM_MAJOR) IS NULL AND TRIM(MAJRCODE) IS NULL) OR (TRIM(M.SRM_MAJOR) = TRIM(MAJRCODE))) 
  ;

EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    IF DEBUGGER = 'Y' THEN
      ATTSCODE := SQLERRM;
    ELSE
      RETURN;  
    END IF;
END CURRICULUM_TRANSLATE2;
```

If I test this procedure and enter the data, all specified as strings.

```
collcode = School of Theology
degrcode = Master of Divinity
majrcode = General
termcode = 999999
debugger = Y
```

I get no results. I can tell because my ATTSCODE returns:

```
ORA-01403: no data found
```

However, when I modify the query to have hard-coded values, like this:

```
  procedure CURRICULUM_TRANSLATE2 (DEGRCODE IN OUT VARCHAR2,
                                 COLLCODE IN OUT VARCHAR2,
                                 MAJRCODE IN OUT VARCHAR2,
                                 RESDCODE IN OUT VARCHAR2,
                                 LEVLCODE IN OUT VARCHAR2,
                                 STYPCODE IN OUT VARCHAR2,
                                 TERMCODE IN OUT VARCHAR2,
                                 ATTSCODE IN OUT VARCHAR2,
                                 DEBUGGER IN     VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL)
IS
VARPROG       VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
  SELECT
    T.DEGRCODE,
    T.PROGCODE,
    T.MAJRCODE,
    T.COLLCODE,                             
    T.LEVLCODE,
    T.STYPCODE,
    T.ATTSCODE
  INTO
   DEGRCODE,
   VARPROG ,
   MAJRCODE,
   COLLCODE,                             
   LEVLCODE,
   STYPCODE,
   ATTSCODE
  FROM 
    MAJORLOOKUP T
  JOIN (SELECT SRM_COLLEGE, SRM_DEGREE, SRM_MAJOR, MAX(SRM_TERM_EFFECTIVE) AS MAXTERM
        FROM   MAJORLOOKUP
        WHERE  SRM_TERM_EFFECTIVE <= TERMCODE
        GROUP BY SRM_COLLEGE, SRM_DEGREE, SRM_MAJOR) M  
    ON  M.SRM_COLLEGE = T.SRM_COLLEGE 
    AND M.SRM_DEGREE = T.SRM_DEGREE 
    AND ((T.SRM_MAJOR IS NULL AND M.SRM_MAJOR IS NULL)           OR 
         (T.SRM_MAJOR IS NULL AND M.SRM_MAJOR ='Not Applicable') OR 
         (T.SRM_MAJOR IS NULL AND UPPER(M.SRM_MAJOR) ='NONE')    OR 
         (T.SRM_MAJOR = M.SRM_MAJOR)) 
  WHERE T.SRM_TERM_EFFECTIVE = M.MAXTERM
  AND TRIM(M.SRM_COLLEGE) = TRIM('School of Theology')
  AND TRIM(M.SRM_DEGREE) = TRIM('Master of Divinity')
  AND ((TRIM(M.SRM_MAJOR) IS NULL AND TRIM('General') IS NULL) OR (TRIM(M.SRM_MAJOR) = TRIM('General'))) 
  ;

EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    IF DEBUGGER = 'Y' THEN
      ATTSCODE := SQLERRM;
    ELSE
      RETURN;  
    END IF;
END CURRICULUM_TRANSLATE2;
```

I get the return I'm looking for.

This is the create script for the table I'm working with:

```
-- Create table
create table MAJORLOOKUP
(
  srm_college        VARCHAR2(4000),
  srm_degree         VARCHAR2(4000),
  srm_major          VARCHAR2(4000),
  srm_term_effective NUMBER,
  degrcode           VARCHAR2(4000),
  progcode           VARCHAR2(4000),
  majrcode           VARCHAR2(4000),
  collcode           VARCHAR2(4000),
  levlcode           VARCHAR2(4000),
  stypcode           VARCHAR2(4000),
  attscode           VARCHAR2(4000)
)
tablespace USERS
  pctfree 10
  initrans 1
  maxtrans 225
  storage
  (
    initial 64K
    minextents 1
    maxextents unlimited
  );
```

I've been able to replicate this in two environments.

I've also had success with the same procedure but having the `TERMCODE` variable in the procedure. But when I swap the hard-coded text out and use any other variable, I get no results.

I've tried reworking the self-join on the table, but I get the same error.

Many thanks.

=============EDITS================

Thank you for the responses. I've updated the first code block to be the procedure with the variables in place. I've also updated the input variables and output code. My apologies for the previous oversight.

Generalized the table name

Comment: I can't see difference between 2 PL/SQL blocks. They are identical. Something missing.

Comment: And also it's not good practice to name columns, variables and parameters in same convention with same names, it can be a serious headache.

Comment: It's likely to be a scope problem because of the naming issue Seyran mentioned, but it would be helpful if you could include the version of the code that uses variables *and* the actual call you're making to that.

Comment: Unless you are passing `debugger` as `Y` then you suppress all exceptions, so anything could be happening. Are you sure you are setting it? btw I've never heard of "a no value returned" error.